# Como usar aspas dentro de aspas e trocar palavra de dentro do argumento?

Tags: python, string, syslog

Rodando o

```
os.system("reg add "caminho\caminho\caminho\caminho\"")
```

e se poderem mais ainda, tem como eu escolher uma palavra no meio desse comando e substituir por outra??

Comment: Bem vindo ao site. Dê uma olhada na minha resposta e veja se te ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Para usar aspas dentro de uma definição de string, você precisa escapá-la com `\`.

Assim:

```
"meu nome é \"wallace\"
```

O resultado será:

```
'meu nome é "wallace"'
```

Você também poderia substituir as aspas duplas pelas simples, para facilitar a legibilidade dessa definição:

```
'meu nome é "Wallace"'
```

Para substituir um trecho específico, utilize o método `replace` da sua `str`.

Assim:

```
'meu nome é Robin'.replace('Robin', 'Wallace')
```

O resultado será:

```
'meu nome é Wallace'
```

## Minhas considerações e recomendações

Para executar esse comando, eu não escaparia a string, e sim, utilizaria a formatação da `str`, para melhorar a legibilidade, assim:

```
cmd = 'reg add "{0}"'.format("caminho\caminho\caminho")

os.system(cmd)
```

Ou ainda usando o operador `%` para definir a `str`.

```
caminho = "caminho\caminho\caminho"
cmd = "reg add "%s"' % caminho;
```